# Flutter firebase_auth loading screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I've recently implemented a "Sign in with google" in my Flutter app. But while the app is doing the login itself there's only a transparent screen, no loading wheel, nothing. Does anybody know how can I change this login screen?

My code:

```
handleAuthState() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return HomeScreen();
        } else {
          return const LoginScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // signInWithGoogle
  signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
        await GoogleSignIn(scopes: <String>["Email"]).signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser!.authentication;
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use ConnectionState.waiting

```
handleAuthState() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
       return Container(); // RETURN CIRCLELOADING OR SOMETHING SIMILAR
    }
   
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return HomeScreen();
    } else {
      return const LoginScreen();
    }
  },
);
```

}

#### Reference

[ConnectionState Enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState.html)

Comment: Just tried, didn't work :(